# Indexing instances in AWS cloudformation auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup a AutoScalingGroup and somehow index instances in it. I need unique hostnames for:

- DNS
- Configuration management

This is easy with OpenStack HEAT - ResourceGroup (just use %index%) but I am struggling in AWS world with similar functionality...

So basically what I need is for example:

hostname-0, hostname-1, hostname-2... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to execute a script in the user-data of each instance that sets the instance's hostname [1] based on some logic. Instead of changing the hostname you could set the instance's "Name" tag value [2]. You could then use the AWS CLI or API to get the hostname from the "Name" tag. This may be simpler if your use-case permits it.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html
[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html

Comment: I know how to set a hostname, tag, dns etc. that is not a problem. Problem is to make use of some index within auto scaling group. So for example if I will have 2 hosts they will be called

`hostname-0 and hostname-1`

Then if I will update group with third host I want it to be called:
`-hostname-2`

Comment: You can track and increment a counter in any datastore like DynamoDB. You could even do an API call to get the count of instances currently in the group and add 1 to it. But are you sure that's a good idea? Autoscaling can terminate an instance based on your scaling policy and the indexes won't have much meaning.

Comment: I am currently looking into creating groups of hosts (non auto scaling -> min count = max count) , a fixed number of slaves to be precise. Tracking them in DB doesn't make any sense, it's way too complicated. I can do logic on my side based on many things eg. my config management, describing the group itself etc - but it's all manual and adds complexity. It's hard to belive there is nothing simple like index available there..

Comment: Sorry, as of currently there is no automated way to do what you described.

Comment: We have "solved" this problem by creating singleton autoscaling groups. E.g. for Zookeeper we have 5 autoscaling groups of min and max count of 1. The downside is that you cannot have real scaling. And you have to implement rolling deploys by using the dependsOn attribute

Comment: Not sure why jbird was downvoted. His solution would work for a real auto-scaling (meaning not static instance counts) environment. I don't see the point of an autoscale group with min/max set to 1. You can write lambda scripts to handle self-healing and re-deploying.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a new feature since the OP happened, but you can access this via meta-data after launch:

curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index

Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: This is always 0 for instances in an ASG.

Answer (score 0):

every instances in ami-launch-index gets 0, So it cannot be used for this purpose.